Is there any way to perform a check before token acquisition when using MSAL Angular loginRedirect()?
I'm currently authenticating users in my Angular app using MSAL Angular connected to Entra AD. It all works perfectly, however I would like to perform an additional check on my database before the tokens are acquired.
The flow would go something like this:

The user gets redirected to the Microsoft login page using loginRedirect()
User inputs login information
Check is performed
If the check succeeds: acquire tokens, if not: deny access

My current solution is to just perform this check AFTER loginRedirect() successful authentication, but the problem with this is that the tokens would already be acquired before I perform the check.
This is my current implementation:

export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = async (route, state) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  await authService.getMSALInstance().initialize();
  const response = await authService.getMSALInstance().handleRedirectPromise();
  if (response && response.account) {
    authService.getMSALInstance().setActiveAccount(response.account);
  }

  if (authService.getMSALInstance().getAllAccounts().length > 0 && someCheck(someUserInfo))) {
    return true;
  } else {
    authService.getMSALInstance().loginRedirect();
    return false;
  }
};

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You might want to look into using a custom claims provider so that you can do all of this on the backend instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/custom-claims-provider-overview
